# App got rejected because only using Facebook as login option?

Tags: ios, app-store, facebook-login, appstore-approval

My app is a photo-sharing app based on Facebook, and Facebook is the only option for register and login, but my app got rejected with following message:

> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be
>   rejected:
>
> We found that your app uses Facebook login for authentication purposes
>   only - but does not include any account-based features offered by that
>   site. This is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> It would be appropriate to modify your app to include account-based
>   features of that social network - or use your own authentication
>   mechanism.

But clearly my app is based on Facebook and user could share photo to Facebook, and invite their Facebook friend to join, so I dont see our app is using Facebook login for "authentication purposes only".

Any help is appreciate!

Comment: This just annoys me. Isn't facebook now often used as an OpenID, like google? Other apps do this. Netflix for example. Unusable without logging in with an email - although I think theirs is their own login.

Comment: A user can already share their photos to Facebook via the Photos app (thanks to Facebook integration with iOS). What additional features does your app provide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Respond to the reviewer explaining that, providing steps on how to do it. It's possible that functionality was just overlooked.

Comment: +1. Reviewers are people too, and will make mistakes. I once added Google Maps support using UIWebView and got rejected for hiding the Google logo/Copyright, even though it was fully visible in the screenshot they had taken.

Comment: Reviewers are people too?? True, but sometimes they are very myopic and appear to be following the 'guidelines' to rigidly - or just interpret them themselves. I've had conversations with them in the resolution centre before - it might as well have been computer generated responses...

Comment: Admittedly, it's hit or miss.

Comment: Thanks! I just reply them and said that we do have feature based on Facebook, and the app got accepted in 10mins.

Comment: If they still dont accept, attach a video demonstrating all the instance of FB integration. Apple did Meta rejection of one of my app and video solved the issue